# Is Gandalf the White as old as Gandalf the Grey? Did he gain a new physical form or just wore different clothes?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings

After his fight with the Balrog, Gandalf died, or so it is told. Because he was one of the Istari, he came back. Did he have a new physical form or was it the old Gandalf we know and love? Did his age become 1 again from 54960 or something?

Comment: This is not explained in the movie but you might get a better answer from our friends over at SF&F.

Comment: See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176174/are-there-characters-from-tolkiens-legendarium-that-came-back-from-the-dead/176240#176240

Comment: Actually, this is quite specifically answered over there - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80317/what-happened-to-gandalf-the-greys-body-when-he-was-sent-back-as-gandalf-the-wh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gandalf the Grey and White are the same person. Gandalf dies in the Fellowship of the Ring, and, staying true to his of the Istari, he comes back in The Two Towers and he becomes Gandalf the White.